# constructor cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, oop

I have a base class called Shape where Point is another class that just contains the x and y coordinates:

```
abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape> {
  public Point position;
  public double area;


  public Shape(Point p){
    position.x  = p.x; 
    position.y  = p.y;
  }
```

Now I have a class called Rectangle that extends Shape 
Note: position is of type Point.

```
public Rectangle(Point p0, double w, double h) {
    // Initializing the postition 
    super(Point(0,0));
    position.x = p0.x;
    position.y = p0.y; 
    // Initializing the height and the width 
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

Now I know that need to call the Shape constructor first which I did by using super but now the compiler is telling that it cannot find the symbol. How do you go on fixing this? 
Here is the error:

```
    ./Rectangle.java:21: error: constructor Shape in class Shape cannot be applied to given types;
  {  // Initialzing of the postition 
  ^
  required: Point
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: why do you need to do `super(Point(0,0));` - you already have a `Point` Object

Comment: `super(p0)`? Also, `position.x` and `position.y` are odd looking assignments - what's `position`?

Comment: position is of Type Point

Comment: even without the super(Point(0,0)) it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Please post the error

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be:

```
public Rectangle(Point p0, double w, double h)
{
    // Initialzing of the postition 
    super(p0);
    // Initialzing the height and the width 
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

Because your super is `Shape` constructor.

Are you sure `Rectangle` extends `Shape`? If you can post your class `Rectangle` definition

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this..

```
public Rectangle(Point p0, double w, double h) {
    // Initializing the postition 
    super(new Point(0,0));
    position.x = p0.x;
    position.y = p0.y; 
    // Initializing the height and the width 
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

You have missed the new keyword in super constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your classes are something like:

```
public class Point {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class Shape {
    public Point position;

    public Shape(Point p) {
        position.x = p.x;
        position.y = p.y;
    }
}
```

And the super constructor of the Rectangle class should receive a Point object, because it extends from Shape, which constructor parameter is a Point, so the class should look like:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape{

    public double width;
    public double height;

    public Rectangle(Point p0, double w, double h) { 
        // Initialzing of the postition
        super(p0);

        // Initialzing the height and the width
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
}
```